# How to extract initrd image from RHEL iso and put a script in initrd /bin/

Tags: filesystems, system-installation, initrd

I have written a customized shell script(command) ,which i want to put in initrd /bin and then, i want it to be copied to Linux OS /opt/xyz directory .Where xyz is customized directory created during installation.

How can i achieve this task.

Answer (score 0):

How to ?

get a sample redhat initramfs

```
cp /boot/initramfs-2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64.img initramfs.img
```

what have we got ?

- initramfs.img:      gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Thu Oct 22 07:04:25 2015, max compression

gunzip it

```
gunzip < initramfs.img > initramfs.stage1
```

- initramfs.stage1:   ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC)

extract it

```
cpio -icv < initramfs.stage1
(lots of line)
usr/sbin
usr/sbin/eject
usr/sbin/chroot
96258 blocks
```

add my stuff

```
mkdir opt/xyz
date > opt/xyz/foo.txt
```

no leading `/` !!

remake the cpio (I delete initramfs.* files)

```
find . -type f -print | cpio -ocv > ../newinitram.stage2
(lots of lines)
./usr/bin/mkfifo
./usr/sbin/eject
./usr/sbin/chroot
96186 blocks
```

what have we got ?

- ../newinitram.stage2: ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC)

now, compress it.

```
gzip -9 < ../newinitram.stage2 > newinitrd.stage3
```

- newinitrd.stage3:                              gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Sat Dec 19 06:32:08 2015, max compression

now, booting your kernel should be easy.

Comment: Thanks.So, if i have iso image ,then how can i extract initrd and again compress it and put it back to iso .So,that during installation my changes will be effective.

Comment: 0 - Given that you want to edit initrd, I thought you know how to build a iso file/disk, however you are not intending to put  a whole application in initrd ? 1- I don't have my iso building scripts at hand, I'll be replying tomorrow. 2- If you feel this question as helpfull you might gav point.