# Problem extracting the "initrd" archive in kernel 5.4

Tags: kernel, initrd, cpio

I can see my `initrd` is occupied almost 90 MB of disk but after extracting it via `cpio` , it contains only a 30 KB microcode :

```
$ cpio -it < initrd.img-5.4.0-18-generic 
.
kernel
kernel/x86
kernel/x86/microcode
kernel/x86/microcode/AuthenticAMD.bin
62 blocks
```

I know that there should be a lot of files and tools which are needed by the kernel in the first stage of booting , but I cannot find anything useful in it.

```
$ file initrd.img-5.4.0-18-generic 
initrd.img-5.4.0-18-generic: ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC)
```

I took a look at [here](https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/linux/articles/l-initrd/) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250378/how-to-extract-initrd-image-from-rhel-iso-and-put-a-script-in-initrd-bin) and [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163346/why-is-it-that-my-initrd-only-has-one-directory-namely-kernel) but these are too old and don't work for me.My `initrd.img` is not a `gzip` archive .
How to extract that file properly?
I use kernel v.5.4.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`initramfs` images contain multiple `cpio` archives; the name of your file suggests you’re using a Ubuntu derivative, so the simplest option for you to list the full contents is to use `lsinitramfs`:

```
lsinitramfs initrd.img-5.4.0-18-generic
```

To extract the contents, use `unmkinitramfs`:

```
unmkinitramfs initrd.img-5.4.0-18-generic initramfs
```

This will extract all the files to the `initramfs` directory.