# How to decompress and compress initramfs?

Tags: linux, initramfs

I want to modify the content in `initramfs`, but I don't know how to decompress and compress after executing the command `sudo update-initramfs -c -k 6.4.0-rt8`? It seems like the command `sudo cpio -idv < initrd.img-6.4.0-rt8`  can, but why is there only one `kernel` directory.

After executing `lsinitramfs initrd.img-6.4.0-rt8 | less`, it seems like there are many files?

This `initramfs` file is intended for use by other systems, not the current system.

```
#sudo update-initramfs -c -k 6.4.0-rt8
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-6.4.0-rt8

#sudo cpio -idv < initrd.img-6.4.0-rt8
#ls 
initrd.img-6.4.0-rt8  kernel
```

Thank you very much for pointing out [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/581266/problem-extracting-the-initrd-archive-in-kernel-5-4), but it solved my decompression problem. What should I do if I modify the decompression file and want to recompress it?

I am using `Debian12`.

Comment: There are different methods for compressing the initramfs. Read the documentation of your used operating system.